# How to calculate consecutive holidays based on a pattern by dplyr package in R

Tags: r, dplyr

According to experts, holidays affect the sales of a shop. Sales are high during consecutive holidays. Consecutive holidays are defined as follows:

**Consider a non-holiday day between two holidays as a holiday**.

[image]

If a day is not a holiday, there is a holiday before and after it; that day is considered a holiday as calculated in column HL_UP. In column HL_DONW, the number of days that are holidays is calculated. We only have the variable IS_HOLIDAY,  How to calculate columns HL_UP and HL_DONW in R using dplyr package?

Here is the data:

```
data_temp <- structure(list(date_1 = c("2021-01-01", "2021-01-02", "2021-01-03", 
"2021-01-04", "2021-01-05", "2021-01-06", "2021-01-07", "2021-01-08", 
"2021-01-09", "2021-01-10", "2021-01-11", "2021-01-12", "2021-01-13", 
"2021-01-14", "2021-01-15", "2021-01-16", "2021-01-17", "2021-01-18", 
"2021-01-19", "2021-01-20", "2021-01-21", "2021-01-22", "2021-01-23", 
"2021-01-24", "2021-01-25", "2021-01-26", "2021-01-27", "2021-01-28"
), IS_HOLIDAY = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-28L))
```

In first step I am trying to define new column that find days between two holidays:

```
data_temp2<-data_temp %>% mutate(
  HL=if_else( IS_HOLIDAY == 0 & lag(IS_HOLIDAY,1)==1 & lead(IS_HOLIDAY,1)==1,1,IS_HOLIDAY))
```

Here is the output:

[image]

Still I do not know how to calculate HL_UP and HL_DOWN.

EDIT:

I think I found a solution:

```
data_temp3<-data_temp2 %>%
  group_by(group_seq = with(rle(HL), rep(seq_along(lengths), lengths))) %>%
  mutate(HL_UP=sum(HL)) %>%
  mutate(HL_DOWN=sum(IS_HOLIDAY))
```

Here is the output:

[image]

I do not understand this part of code:

```
with(rle(...), rep(seq_along(lengths), lengths))
```

Comment: To understand rle (run lenght encoding) part, split it into pieces to examine each part separately, i.e. `rle_ <- rle(data_temp2$HL); seq_ <- seq_along(rle_$lengths); rep_ <- rep(seq_, rle_$lengths)` . `with()` allows to use rel object returned from `rel()` in a dplyr pipeline without storing it in the environment first, `lengths` is one of 2 components in that rle object, `seq_along(lengths)` returns a vector `1:8` (there are 8 runs in this example), each value ending up as unique run id, needed, as rle values themselves (1s and 0s) aren't unique, thus can't be used for grouping.

Answer (score 1):

We can also use `zoo::rollapply` here to determine is `IS_HOLIDAY` should be changed, and then count rows (for UP) and sum IS_HOLIDAY (for DOWN).

```r
data_temp %>%
  mutate(holiday2 = zoo::rollapply(IS_HOLIDAY, 3, FUN = function(z) case_when(length(z) <= 2 ~ z[length(z)], TRUE ~ if_else((all(z[c(1,3)] > 0) || z[2] > 0), 1, z[2])), align = "center", partial = TRUE)) %>%
  group_by(grp = cumsum(c(FALSE, diff(holiday2) != 0))) %>%
  mutate(HL_DOWN = if_else(first(IS_HOLIDAY) > 0, n(), 0L), HL_UP = if_else(first(IS_HOLIDAY) > 0, sum(IS_HOLIDAY > 0), 0L)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-grp) %>%
  print(n=99)
# # A tibble: 28 × 5
#    date_1     IS_HOLIDAY holiday2 HL_DOWN HL_UP
#    <chr>           <dbl>    <dbl>   <int> <int>
#  1 2021-01-01          0        0       0     0
#  2 2021-01-02          0        0       0     0
#  3 2021-01-03          0        0       0     0
#  4 2021-01-04          0        0       0     0
#  5 2021-01-05          0        0       0     0
#  6 2021-01-06          0        0       0     0
#  7 2021-01-07          1        1       1     1
#  8 2021-01-08          0        0       0     0
#  9 2021-01-09          0        0       0     0
# 10 2021-01-10          0        0       0     0
# 11 2021-01-11          0        0       0     0
# 12 2021-01-12          1        1       3     2
# 13 2021-01-13          0        1       3     2
# 14 2021-01-14          1        1       3     2
# 15 2021-01-15          0        0       0     0
# 16 2021-01-16          0        0       0     0
# 17 2021-01-17          1        1       5     4
# 18 2021-01-18          1        1       5     4
# 19 2021-01-19          0        1       5     4
# 20 2021-01-20          1        1       5     4
# 21 2021-01-21          1        1       5     4
# 22 2021-01-22          0        0       0     0
# 23 2021-01-23          0        0       0     0
# 24 2021-01-24          0        0       0     0
# 25 2021-01-25          0        0       0     0
# 26 2021-01-26          0        0       0     0
# 27 2021-01-27          1        1       2     2
# 28 2021-01-28          1        1       2     2
```